# Is boost::asio equivalent to Poco::Net?

Tags: boost-asio, poco-libraries

I am part of a project that is using `boost` as a c++ library. Now we want to use SMTP/POP3/SSL/HTTP/HTTPS. I detected several fitting classes and functions in `Poco::Net`

- Poco::Net::POP3ClientSession
- Poco::Net::MailMessage
- Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession
- Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession
- Poco::Net::HTTPRequest

I could not find anything equivalent in `boost::asio`. Before I make my final decision, I want to ask the community, if I am right, or if there is something similar in `boost`...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although there is some overlap, Boost.Asio is not the equivalent of POCO's Net library.  Higher-level protocols are outside of the scope for Boost.Asio. The [rationale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html) of the library explicitly states that it is a tookit, rather than a framework, that has been designed to support the development of other libraries that provide higher levels of abstraction, such as HTTP.  Furthermore, I am not aware of any Boost libraries (released or candidates) that provide support for higher-level protocols.  One alternative may be the [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) library, which is still in development, and aims to provide support for higher-level protocols.  However, it currently only has an HTTP client and server implemented.

If you are looking for higher-level protocol support, then [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) is could be a good candidate.  However, before making a decision, I would suggest considering other points:

- Support: On StackOverflow [boost-asio](/questions/tagged/boost-asio) appears to be more active than [poco-libraries](/questions/tagged/poco-libraries).  Other avenues for support include the [Boost Mailing List](http://www.boost.org/community/groups.html) and the [POCO fourms](http://pocoproject.org/forum/).
- Boost.Asio is designed to be a toolkit and leverages generic programming.  While POCO provides some functionality through non-framework means, some of the higher-level functionality is only provided through frameworks.  As such, it introduces a tighter coupling with the application, and may affect an application's design.
- Asynchronous programming between the two libraries is slightly different.  In POCO, callbacks are associated to an event type, allowing a callback to be executed multiple times for a single subscription.  On the other hand, Boost.Asio associates a callback to a single operation, resulting in a callback being called at most once for a given operation.  This difference can have consequences in how the asynchronous chains are designed and flow.